# How to stream mp3 files using URL [SERVER/FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, server, streaming, mp3

**I want to stream mp3 files** through url for example:

[https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/Music_for_Video/springtide/Sounds_strange_weird_but_unmistakably_romantic_Vol1/springtide_-*03*-_We_Are_Heading_to_the_East.mp3](https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/Music_for_Video/springtide/Sounds_strange_weird_but_unmistakably_romantic_Vol1/springtide_-_03_-_We_Are_Heading_to_the_East.mp3)
[image]

The above url starts streaming the audio in the browser itself i want to achieve this in windows 10 for my audio streaming flutter app project, the above URL works just fine but i tried putting a mp3 file in a folder inside htdocs of XAMPP server and as i opened the browser and followed the url to file in my localhost it started downloading it instead of streaming like the URL i have mentioned above, how can i achieve this because the URL above works fine with my flutter app but not the file that i hosted on my local machine (Windows 10) using XAMPP Apache server.